# List of anchors next being clicked not working

Tags: jquery, click, siblings

I have a list of anchor tags that each each the content in a div, I then have controls that can go back and forth through the content being loaded. But I can't get it to fire the click() on the next or previous sibling:

```
            var current;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", "EPUBS/" + localStorage.book, false);
            if(request.overrideMimeType){
                request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
            }
            request.send();
            var file = request.responseText;
            var zip =  new JSZip(file);
            var $content = $(zip.file(localStorage.selected + "/toc.ncx").asText()).find("navPoint");
            $content.each(function(){
                $('#navbar').append("<a href = '#' id = '" + $(this).children('content').attr('src') + "' > " + $(this).children('navLabel').children('text').text() + "</a><br/>");
            });

$("#navbar > a").click(function(event) {   
    event.preventDefault();
    var t2 = ($(this).attr('id')).split("#");
    var $tr = $(zip.file("6130/" + t2[0]).asText());
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = "";
    $('#main').append('<h1>' + $(this).text() + '</h1>');
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += $tr.text();
    current = t2;    
});

$("#prev").click(function(event) {    
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#' + current).prev().click();    
});

$("#next").click(function(event) {    
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#' + current).next().click();    
});

        <div id = 'navbar'>
    </div>

    <div id = 'main'>
        <h1 id = 'mHeading'>Book</h1>
        <img src = 'book.png' width = '500px'/>
        <p id = "d"></p>
    </div>

    <div id = 'controls'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width = "12%"><a href = "#"  id = "c1" onclick = "document.getElementById('main').style.color = 'black'; document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundColor = 'white';">black on white</a></td>
                <td width = "12%"><a href = "#"  id = "c2" onclick = "document.getElementById('main').style.color = 'white'; document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundColor = 'black';">white on black</a></td>
                <td width = "10%"></td>
                <td><a href = "#"  id = "prev" ><</a></td>
                <td><a href = "#"  id = "next" >></a></td>
                <td width = "5%"><a href = "#" id = "s1" style = "font-size: 12px" onclick = "document.getElementById('main').style.fontSize = '14px'">A</a></td>
                <td width = "5%"><a href = "#" id = "s1" style = "font-size: 16px"  onclick = "document.getElementById('main').style.fontSize = '16px'">A</a></td>
                <td width = "5%"><a href = "#" id = "s1" style = "font-size: 20px"  onclick = "document.getElementById('main').style.fontSize = '20px'">A</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Am I writing it out wrong ? The first .click function works perfectly

EDIT: added the rest of the code, but it uses a lot of external files that are loaded in, they work however, I just can't get to the next or previous anchor added in the first click method

Comment: Can you copy in your HTML, plus the variable 'current' initialisation? Alternatively, make a jsFiddle of your current solution - makes it easier to figure out what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

In last two functions *current* is undefined.

Comment: I declared current at the start of my code, I've alerted it and it is, sorry bout that though.

Comment: Ok, so are you sure that $("#"+current) is valid object?

Comment: Try alert($('#' + current).html());

Comment: @RickDonohoe it seems my current is still broken

Comment: @RickDonohoe I can call it with alert(document.getElementById(current).innerHTML); and that works fine.

Comment: @Crossman The `.split()` function returns an array of elements, so string concatenation won't work.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I changed that now to just the id of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think split() is necessary since the ID returned should be a String anyway. I would use:

```
current = $(this).attr('id');
```

and I don't know how this works exactly, but I'd assume it would be worth-wile setting current as a default value when you declare it? (If  for any reason the last 2 click functions get called before the first one?)